# How to print the Scale value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

In order to normalize the data I used `MinMaxScaler` as follows:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
```

I would like to know the scale value, any ideas ? I've seen that before in a code somewhere, and  I don't remember how it'd done.

ie: I'm not good in python, so I'll try to explain it simply. If I can label the `scale value` by `A` (`A==scale value`), then: `scaled = A * values`
I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the `A` here (which is the scale value).

I tried scaler.value but it doesn't work, it shows some error.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show the specific problem with a small test case, and clarify your question with respect to those values.  Your current code and question have too many undefined terms.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
values = [[0, 10], [1, 18]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
print(scaled)

[[0. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Comment: The transformation is given by :
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min

Please check https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: When using MinMaxScaler, it is necessary to know it is a Normalization and not a simple multiplication. In order to get the scaled values we use this formula:

 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

where :
* X : is the actual value 
* Xmin: is the minimal value within the dataset
* Xmax: is the maximum value within the dataset
* Xnew: is the new value which is between 0 and 1. 

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZkEz.png

Comment: I don't have access to comment section !!!